# sessions in codeigniter

Tags: session, codeigniter

When you set a session in code igniter, lets say in the controller after login,

how do you access the custom session date in the view, should I access it directly from view lets say, echo "$this->session->userid" or should I pass the data in to the view via the controller?

I know the session is globally available, but want to keep the design consistent with mvc.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why accessing it directly on your view would be bad =)

Comment: Accessing directly from view is bad because the standard is to pass variables to view through one array.

Answer (score 4):

Pass it from the controller to view:

**Controller Code:**

```
$data['date'] = $this->session->userdata('date');
$this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

**View Code:**

```
echo $date;
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Keep in mind you may need to load the session class in your controller if you don't have it [autoloaded](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html):

```
$this->load->library('session');
```